# Dynamic push notifications w/ Onesignal, Nuxtjs and Prismic CMS

Tags: progressive-web-apps, onesignal, prismic.io, nuxtjs

I'm building a PWA using Nuxtjs that's fetching blog content from a [prismic api](https://prismic.io/). OneSignal has been installed and configured following the documentation provided [here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/onesignal-module) and I was able to subscribe a user to the app and deliver the welcome push along with other push via OneSignal's dashboard.

I now want to send push notifications whenever new content is posted to the blog. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I am triggering the push notification whenever a user goes to https://example.com/blog. NB: prismic sorts by latest post so `this.docs[0]` fetches the latest article from the array.

```
    async fetch() {
    try {
        const query = await this.$prismic.api.query(this.$prismic.predicates.at('document.type', 'blog_posts'), {pageSize: 6}).then((query)=>{
        this.docs = query.results;
        const requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": `Basic ${process.env.API_KEY}`},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                app_id: process.env.APP_ID,
                included_segments: ["All"],
                contents: {en: this.docs[0].data.post_content[0].text},
                headings: {en: this.docs[0].data.post_title[0].text},
                chrome_web_image: this.docs[0].data.featured_image.url,
                big_picture: this.docs[0].data.featured_image.url,
                web_url: `https://example.com/blog/${this.docs[0].uid}`
            })                
        }; fetch('https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications', requestOptions)
        })
    } catch (e) {
        // Send to bugsnag
        console.log(e)
    }
}, fetchDelay: 500,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prismic allows you set webhooks that trigger when a document is published. See [prismic blog](https://prismic.io/blog/prismic-webhooks). Using express, I created one that will do two things:

1. **Get all blog post from prismic**
2. **Send onesignal web push notification when post is published**

See code snippet here: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2003202

References:

- [Prismic Node Integration](https://prismic.io/docs/nodejs/getting-started/integrating-with-an-existing-project)
- [Bearer.sh Guide on webhook listeners](https://blog.bearer.sh/consuming-webhooks-with-node-js-and-express/)